# reload table view : indexPath isn't reset ios 6

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, reload

I'm making an iOS 6 program which downloads JSON data from a website and displays it in a table view. I added a pull to refresh method witch works fine. I can go in the settings view controller (secondViewController) and change the address, everything works. Then, I use the pull to refresh method and my tableView is reloaded. But if I reload 3 times AFTER changing the address, my app crashes. I get this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ca1012 0x10dee7e 0x1c430b4 0x3084 0xdd8fb 0xdd9cf 0xc61bb 0xd6b4b 0x732dd 0x10f26b0   0x229dfc0 0x229233c 0x2292150 0x22100bc 0x2211227 0x22bb333 0x22bb75f 0x1c60376 0x1c5fe06 0x1c47a82 0x1c46f44 0x1c46e1b 0x1bfb7e3 0x1bfb668 0x22ffc 0x1fbd 0x1ee5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What am I doing wrong ? And how can I fix that problem ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your app is crashing because array with which you are loading the table is empty. Where are you changing the value in your array? You need to put some more code of your uitableview delegate.

Comment: have you allocated the array?

Comment: the problem is that I followed a tutorial and I used that city function so I don't really know how to handle it. the only thing I did is    City * currentCity = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key design consideration that leaps out is that your `retreiveData` method is clearly updating the model (the `citiesArray`) asynchronously, which means that any interaction with the tableview while this is taking place may fail. You should never asynchronously update the actual `citiesArray` itself. The update to that array should happen in the main queue.

You should change `retrieveData` to not touch the existing `citiesArray`, but rather create and return a new array, and then, in the code you dispatch back to the main queue, only then replace the existing `citiesArray` and call `reloadData`, something like:

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSArray *newCitiesArray = [self retreiveData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (newCitiesArray) {

                // you presumably only want to reload the data if `retrieveData` was successful

                citiesArray = newCitiesArray
                [myTableView reloadData];
            }

            [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });
    });
}
```

Clearly, this will involve some changes to `retrieveData`, too, but hopefully that's self explanatory. If not, update your question with that code, and we can make further suggestions. But we really shouldn't need to go there, as I suspect you understand the change that needs to take place there.

There are other, more subtle issues you might want to tackle, too, such as thinking about whether you really want to use a global queue, which is concurrent (e.g. if you hit refresh while the previous refresh going, do you really want two queries going on concurrently with your server ... because you dispatch the updates back to the main queue you won't crash, but it's inefficient, you're not guaranteed the order that they'll complete, etc.). You might also want to use `NSOperationQueue` in which you can write code to permit the cancellation of previous requests, etc.

But all of this is a little complicated and is of secondary concern to your main issue, the crashing. Refactoring the `retrieveData` code to ensure you don't touch `citiesArray`, itself, as outlined above, should address that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that really helped but I still have a problem : the line    NSArray *newCitiesArray = [self retreiveData];    gives me the error :    initializing 'NS_Array *__strong' with an expression of type 'void'. Why does that happen ?

Comment: @jrock007 To do it this way, you have to change `retrieveData` from a `void` return type to a `NSArray` (or, if you're using mutable arrays, `NSMutableArray`). And then change it so that that method doesn't use `citiesArray`, but create a new variable that you'll use within `retrieveData`, and at the end of that method, return that new array object (or return `nil` if you had any network or JSON parsing errors).

Comment: I found how to fix that problem by myself by changing a bit of code... so Thank you ! You really helped me a lot !